# Input type password - Design issue - Rhodes

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

In my app I am using a form for registration purpose, in this form if i click the password field
some design issue occurs(webkit-border-radius,background color are removed)

Then I tried with Jquery Mobile, there also same problem

Here I have attached the screen shot,
[image1](https://picasaweb.google.com/111035130900690009669/ScrapbookPhotos#5650210653843046642)
[image2](https://picasaweb.google.com/111035130900690009669/ScrapbookPhotos#5650210698964036242)

give me a better solution

- i am using Rhodes 3.0.2

Comment: You'll need to provide code that you're using if you expect to get some help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a jQuery Mobile issue. I would be surprised if it wasn't fixed by now.

Comment: It is not a jQuery Mobile issue.It is Android Platform issue. I have tested at android 2.1,2.2,3.0 All the platform having this issue. I solved this by using one jquery fancy password plugin